# How to concat JArray element in Postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have table with columns: `id` (pk) and `tasks` (json), with e.g. `[{ "name": "xxx"}, ..]`

How can I get results like: id, ..,"xxx,...", how to concatenate from the Json array in the `tasks` column?

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you want. You mention "concatenate" but your example indicates you want the opposite: _extract_ values from the json array. Can you please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add more detailed sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables.

Comment: What do you want, if `name` occurs in multiple elements inside the array?

Answer (score 0):

The source data (table) looks like:

`Id`   ... `tasks`

`1`    ...  `[{"name": "abc",...},{"name: "abd", ...}, ...]`

I would like to query out: 
`1` ... `"abc, abd, ..."`

I figured out the following way:

```
with tmp_data(id, val) as (values (1, '[{ "name": "abc", "col": false }, { "name": "abc", "col": true }]'::json),  (2, '[{"name": "123", "col": true}, {"name": "ghg", "col": true }]'::json)),
    tmp_data_elements(id, elem) as (select id, json_array_elements(val) from tmp_data)
select x.id, string_agg(x.elem::varchar, ', ') as concated
from (select  id, elem->'name' as elem from tmp_data_elements ) x
GROUP BY 1
```